# Display all tweets with a certain hashtag with simple design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm developing some website using Rails. I want to add "our users' tweets" part to the main page. I need an advice how I can do it better. I hoped to get standard way to do it, may be some Twitter widget or something else. I used Google, but I've found nothing. Please, point me to the right path. Sorry if my questions is very simple, but I don't really know how to do it. I hope that I needn't parse JSON and add styles independently; I need simple design from Twitter :)

Comment: And what would be "our users 'tweets'"? Tweets that has a custom hashtag on it? Tweets that mention your twitter username?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your [ambiguous] question, there are a number of things to consider:

> - How will you retrieve the tweets?
> - How will you store / access them?
> - How will the data be displayed on front-end?

The two methods you have are either to use the [Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter), or the [TwitterFetcher JS plugin](http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/#sthash.P48R6QTj.dpbs):

---

**Gem**

The [Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) uses the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/) to pull data from the official Twitter API. This means you've got the throttling & authentication to build into your app

The benefits of using this gem is it gives you a HUGE amount of flexibility with the data. You can pull as much data as you need / want, in whatever format you want - all formatted in JSON & can be displayed on your site

This gem is best suited to storing your tweets, either in a DB or in [Redis](http://redis.io) etc, otherwise you'll have massive synchronous dependency on Twitter's API - which is never good for performance

---

**JS**

The [TwitterFetcher JS plugin](http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/#sthash.P48R6QTj.dpbs) is epic - basically takes a Twitter widget & strips out the HTML, allowing you to style it how you like

This is the most effective way to retrieve Twitter data on-the-fly, as it's asynchronous, relies on Twitter's widget system (far more robust than API), and stores no data locally